# PHP - input a list of input fields into a database

Tags: php, mysql, html

**New.php (form)**
This has a section where you can clone input fields and the values go into array. When posting, these values are then added to the database via a foreach loop.

e.g. `<input type="text" name="number[]" />`

**Edit.php (form)**
I now extract all the rows from the data and put them into a list of input fields.

How do i update a mysql entry for that particular value? Normally with ajax and jquery, i can get the rowid from 'data-rowid' i generated and then update where rowid = x. What about on submit. Would it need to go back into an array or how can i check against a row id?

Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to submit rowid as a hidden input field so it is posted along with all your other information. That way when you get to edit.php you have the information you need.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="1">
```

And then on edit you can do :

```
$rowid = $_POST['rowid'];
```

Comment: How would the PHP / Query(INsert) look like for this example?

Comment: @deanhodges Just like any other Insert query where the `WHERE` is a variable.

Comment: Ahh. Penny drops. Key / Value foreach array. rowid should be "rowid[]" and the field with the data should be "number[]". I wansn't just 1 bit of data it was a list. i.e. a shopping list.